# How can I add firebase rules to allow the access of just one user email with realtime database?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using these rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
      "registries":{
        "uid": {
    "user": {     
         ".read": "auth.token.email.matches(/.*augustomarce100@hotmail.com$/) && auth != null",
        ".write": "auth.token.email.matches(/.*augustomarce100@hotmail.com$/) && auth != null",
}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use these rules too, but they don't work.

```
{
"rules":{
 "user": {
   "$uid": {
     "email": ***<email>*** this part isnt working
   }
 },
 "whitelist": {
   "augustomarce100@hotmail%2Ecom": true,
 }  
 }
}

{
  "rules": {
registries:{
"$uid": {
    "user": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "root.child('whitelist').child(newData.child('email').val().replace('.', '%2E')).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

I want to only allow one email to access the page. I think the whitelist option is the best if I want to add more emails in the future.
Im using this code for login:

```
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { ConfigService } from 'src/app/services/config.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public formLogin: FormGroup;
  public showLoginError: boolean;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afFunction: AngularFireFunctions,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public config: ConfigService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private route: Router
  ) {


    this.formLogin = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      pass: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })
    this.showLoginError = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  /**
   * Compruebo si el login es correcto
   */
  checkLogin() {

    // Cojo el email y el pass
    let email = this.formLogin.get('email').value
    let pass = this.formLogin.get('pass').value

    // Nos logueamos
    this.authService.login(email, pass).then(state => {

      console.log(state);

      this.route.navigate(['/resume'])

    }, error => {
      console.error(error);
      this.showLoginError = true;
    })

  }

   }
```

Im using this code for auth.service:

```
   import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {



  private _isLoggued: boolean;

  set isLoggued(value: boolean) {
    this._isLoggued = value;
  }

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private route: Router
  ){
    this._isLoggued = false;
    // Compruebo si estoy subscrito
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this._isLoggued = true;
        this.route.navigate(['/resume']);
      }
      })
    }
  /**
   * Compruebo si estoy logueado
   */
  isAuthenticated() {
    return this._isLoggued;
  }

  /**
   * Me logueo dado un email y contraseña, devuelve una promesa
   * @param email email del usuario
   * @param pass pass del usuario
   */
  login(email: string, pass: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
  }

  /**
   * Nos desploguea de la aplicacion
   */
  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    this._isLoggued = false;
    this.route.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  /**
   * Comprueba si el usuario existe, dado un email
   * @param email email del usuario a comprobar
   */
  checkAccount(email) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(email);
  }

  /**
   * Devuelve el usuario actual
   */
  currentUser() {
    if (this.afAuth.auth.currentUser) {
      return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.email;
    }
    return '';
  }

  /**
   * Crea una cuenta dado un email y un pass. Devuelve una promesa
   * @param email email del usuario a crear
   * @param pass pass del usuario a crear
   */
  createAccount(email: string, pass: string) {

    // Chequeo si la cuenta existe
   if(this.checkAccount(email)){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('el usuario ya existe')

      })
    } else {
      // Creo la cuenta y devuelvo una promesa con el estado
      return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(authState => {
        return authState;
      }).catch(error => {
        throw error;
      })
    }

  }
  async resetPassword(email: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      return this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Im trying to add more security to my page, i want to only allow full access to some users by email others only for reading, im using realtime database because i got familiarity with it, please some help, im stuck here.

Comment: Rules don't do anything on their own, but only become active (and meaningful) when you execute code against them. Please edit your question to include the [minimal complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and be explicit about what that problem is as "it doesnt work" is not lacking some details.

Comment: i edit it, thats the whole problem im stuck there

Comment: That's a lot of code. Are you sure it's the **minimum** that is needed to reproduce the problem (read the link I posted before please, as it's quite useful). At first glance I don't see any access to the database in that code though. Can you point out in the code exactly where the error comes from?

Comment: everything works fine, the problem is that i want to add firebase rules in realtime database with especific rules, I investigate about it but nothing seems to work.

Comment: i put where the problem is while executing the rules in realtime database